Angular libraries update
In my company we have some custom Angular libraries that we use in most of our projects. The problem we have is that whenever we update the codebase our projects are created from to a new Angular version, we also have to update all libraries, most of the times not touching their code, just updating the Angular library version, to make it compatible with the projects new version. Is there any way to make this easier and not so time consuming?

Firstly you need to check the code for any breaking changes.
Angular update guide
Angular update command
The above sites will help you with that.

To handle the major problem of dependencies not matching and npm install failing, try the below method. Do this after you are 100% certain the code is adjusted with the breaking changes before running the below steps, because you need to handle code breakage from changing versions!

Create a blank project (same version as your main project).
Install the dependencies there one by one.
Once all installed, copy the version numbers from the new project to your application project
Repeat for any number of sub projects

